# how do you create a hdfs data directory?

Tags: hadoop

everytime my hadoop server reboots, I have to format the namenode to start the hadoop. This removes all of the files in my hadoop installation.

I need to move my hadoop hdfs location from /tmp file to permenant location where whenever the server reboots, I don't have to format the namenode etc.

I am very new to hadoop.

1. How do I create a hdfs file in another directory?
2. How do I reference this data directory in config file so that I don't have to format the namenode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two properties of the hdfs-site.xml determine where local files are stored.

The defaults are under /tmp

`dfs.namenode.name.dir`

`dfs.datanode.data.dir`

You typically have to format a namenode only when the HDFS processes failed to terminate correctly (such as a power failure or forced shutdown). It is encouraged to run a standby Namenode to prevent these scenarios.